# How to access sub collection in angular and firestore

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to access a sub-collection inside a document using cloud firestore in angular but it isn't showing the sub-collections and only shows fields and its values

Here is the code. I want to get subCollection names.

```
this.afs.collection(`users/${this.user.uid}/Root`).doc('Folder').valueChanges().subscribe(item => {
    console.log(item);
  });
```

Comment: Expected values?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firestore: Get all items from a 'sub' collection where id = x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49117620/firestore-get-all-items-from-a-sub-collection-where-id-x)

Comment: What is the expected result? Please reponde with @AlexMamo

Comment: Expected value is Folder1 and Folder2. I want the names of subcollections.@AlexMamo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time of writing, the only libraries/SDKs that allow listing the sub-collections of a document are the ones that are used in "trusted server environments" like the ones for Node.js, Java, PHP, etc., see the doc about this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#list_subcollections_of_a_document.

> Retrieving a list of collections is not possible with the mobile/web client libraries

A workaround is to store the sub-collection name(s) in a field (e.g. an array) in the document.

Comment: Thanks for the help.